# UR3_Sim RVIZ Simulation sometimes moves by itself

Tags: ros, rviz

I have a robotic arm simulation (ur3_sim) but when I write 'roslaunch ur3_sim simulation.launch', sometimes it works great and gripper stands steady but for other times, it gives an error, and moves itself:

```
[ERROR] [1680011565.316166357]: Unsupported Gazebo ImageFormat

[ERROR] [1680011565.705340995]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_pan_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.706621423]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_lift_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.708765263]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/elbow_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.711376302]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_1_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.712813562]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_2_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.715457507]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_3_joint [ERROR] [1680011565.716795962]: No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/left_gear_joint
```

PID values not defined anywhere. I don't understand why the simulation moves itself when it starts. simulation link: https://github.com/EuropeanRoverChallenge/ERC-Remote-Maintenance-Sim How can I solve this issue? I cannot find any problems on the Internet like that.

Comment: could it be that the classes responsible for simulating the controllers haven't been initialized when you start the simulation?

Comment: @ignacio how can I understand this? Whether moving itself or not, terminal is seen similar

Comment: try running things [`rosconsole`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration) `logger_level` as `debug`

Comment: I tried but I I didn't understand exactly what and when to write.
@ignacio